# Sort Ember Array on first load only

Tags: ember.js

I have a form with numerous children which I would like to sort alphabetically.

For this I've used an Array Proxy and the SortableMixin on a computed property, the issue I'm experiencing is when a new item is added to the obeserved property the collection sorts itself again.

What I would like to happen is to have the collection sorted on the first load, and then after that not be sorted.

Here's a jsbin example of the current setup, if you click add a new item will be added to the collection, as soon as you start typing in the new item's input the collection will re-sort which is not ideal.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sedexequni/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sort it on the model before hand.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return Ember.Object.create({
      colours:[Ember.Object.create({colour:'red'}), Ember.Object.create({colour:'yello'}), Ember.Object.create({colour:'blue'}), Ember.Object.create({colour:'green'}), Ember.Object.create({colour:'orange'})]
    });
  },
  afterModel: function(model, transition){
     // this will force the collection to populate before 
     // setupController (really applies to async relationship, but whatever)
     // returned promises will block until resolved.
     return model.get('colours'); 
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    var colours = model.get('colours'),
        sort = colours.toArray().sortBy('colour');
    colours.clear();
    colours.pushObjects(sort);
    this._super(controller, model);
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kosanixame/1/edit

Comment: Ok maybe my example was too simplistic - the model is coming from an Ember Data store - so I can't reassign the collection to a sorted version, as per you example.

Comment: Is the relationship async?

Comment: Yes the relationship is async.

Comment: force the colours to populate, clear the collection, refill the collection sorted.